# Wanting to replace pre-installed Windows 8.1 on my Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu. Needed help on which partitions to remove and which to keep

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, partitioning

I have the following partitions right now on my laptop:

1000 MB (Healthy OEM Partition)

260 MB (Healthy EFI System Partition)

1000 MB (Healthy OEM Partition)

462.14 GB (Healthy Boot, Primary Partition): It has my C: drive

12.47 GB (Healthy OEM Partition)

Now I was thinking of completely replacing my Windows with Ubuntu and wanted to know whether I should go ahead with the replacing or not, without doing anything about the partitions? Or should I delete them, make them unallocated, merge them with the 462.14 GB one partition, and THEN replace Windows with Ubuntu? Or any other advise you want to give to me, like to merge only selected partitions, and not all, etc.?

Looking forward for the help from the community. Thanks!   :)

Answer (score 2):

If you download and install the 64 bit version from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and install it from a USB, simply choose the option you are presented with to delete everything and replace with Ubuntu.  The installer will take care of the partitioning for you.

Comment: Oh, you mean I just select 'replace Windows with Ubuntu' and then I don't need to take care of other partitions manually? Also, suppose I dual boot right now, and after a while (a few weeks/months) want to completely remove Windows and just retain Ubuntu (like the case in my original question), would I able to do so, and reclaim all the space in the SDD for Ubuntu itself?

Comment: Dual booting is a completely different issue, that isn't what you asked about in your question.  If you want to dual boot you need to go into windows and do the partitioning up front. Search this site for details.

Comment: I know how to dual boot. I was just asking if it would be possible to remove Windows completely after sometime and reclaim all the space for Ubuntu if I want to in some later time?  :)

Comment: Ok, yeah, you can do that.  You'd have to boot with a live USB, unmount all partitions, and then you could resize the Ubuntu partition after deleting the Windows ones.  It can get complicated though depending on the layout of the partitions.  Like if your swap partition is between the Ubuntu system partition and Windows one, you'd have to move that one too.

Comment: I have SSD, and I read that SSDs don't need to have a swap partition while installing Ubuntu, so I guess that won't be a problem?

Comment: That's a nice feature, I didn't know that.

Comment: If you want to leave Windows for now but possibly delete it and expand Ubuntu into that space later, you might consider using LVM, as detailed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) (among many other places). This is more effort up front, but it will simplify the expansion of Ubuntu, since you can create a new LVM partition ("physical volume") in the space vacated by Windows and expand into it without actually moving any existing data. This is easier and safer than moving and resizing partitions.